# Variables update when they shouldn't

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to make a Pine Script for TradingView that will buy and sell based on MACD but only if the change is large enough. However my lastLong and lastShort variables keep updating even though no trade was made. How do i make sure lastLong and lastShort only update on an actual trade please?

[image]

Edit: Unfortunately the answer suggested didn't fix the issue, the red line (lastShort) disappeared and the blue (lastLong) still updates more often than there are trades.
[image]

```
//@version=4

strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true)
// Variables
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
desiredGain = 1.05
desiredLoss = 1.025
lastLong = 1.0
lastLong := na(lastLong[1]) ? na : lastLong[1]
lastShort = 1.0
lastShort := na(lastShort[1]) ? na : lastShort[1]

inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021, 04, 01, 0, 0))// and (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021, 05, 16, 0, 0))

// Calculation
fastMA = ema(close, fastLength)
slowMA = ema(close, slowlength)
macd = fastMA - slowMA
signal = sma(macd, MACDLength)
esignal = ema(macd, MACDLength)
delta = macd - esignal

didRiseEnough = close/lastLong > desiredGain
didFallEnough = lastShort/close > desiredLoss

if na(lastLong) // If lastLong is uninitialized, run the first entry without checking didFallEnough
    if (inDateRange and crossover(macd, esignal))
        strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
        lastLong := close
else
    if (inDateRange and crossover(macd, esignal) and didFallEnough)
        strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
        lastLong := close
        
if na(lastShort) // If lastShort is uninitialized, run the first entry without checking didRiseEnough
    if (inDateRange and crossunder(macd, esignal))
        strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
        lastShort := close
else
    if (inDateRange and crossunder(macd, esignal) and didRiseEnough)
        strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
        lastShort := close

// Plot
plot(macd * 10 + close/2, color=color.blue)
//plot(signal * 10 + close/2, color=color.orange)
plot(esignal * 10 + close/2, color=color.orange)

plot(lastLong, color=color.blue)
plot(lastShort, color=color.red)

plotshape(didRiseEnough, style=shape.arrowup, color=color.red)
plotshape(didFallEnough, style=shape.arrowdown, color=color.blue)

if (not inDateRange)
    strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare them as `var`, or else they will be re-initialized on every bar.
Also, you must call `crossover()` and `crossunder()` on every bar to avoid the compiler warnings.
I've named them `co` and `cu` in your script.

Please see if this works.
I couldn't check, because you didn't specify on which ticker and timeframe you made your screenshot.

```
//@version=4

strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true)
// Variables
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
desiredGain = 1.05
desiredLoss = 1.025
var lastLong = 1.0
lastLong := na(lastLong[1]) ? na : lastLong[1]
var lastShort = 1.0
lastShort := na(lastShort[1]) ? na : lastShort[1]

inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021, 04, 01, 0, 0))// and (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021, 05, 16, 0, 0))

// Calculation
fastMA = ema(close, fastLength)
slowMA = ema(close, slowlength)
macd = fastMA - slowMA
signal = sma(macd, MACDLength)
esignal = ema(macd, MACDLength)
delta = macd - esignal

didRiseEnough = close/lastLong > desiredGain
didFallEnough = lastShort/close > desiredLoss

co = crossover(macd, esignal)
cu = crossunder(macd, esignal)

if na(lastLong) // If lastLong is uninitialized, run the first entry without checking didFallEnough
    if (inDateRange and co)
        strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
        lastLong := close
else
    if (inDateRange and co and didFallEnough)
        strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
        lastLong := close
        
if na(lastShort) // If lastShort is uninitialized, run the first entry without checking didRiseEnough
    if (inDateRange and cu)
        strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
        lastShort := close
else
    if (inDateRange and cu and didRiseEnough)
        strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
        lastShort := close

// Plot
plot(macd * 10 + close/2, color=color.blue)
//plot(signal * 10 + close/2, color=color.orange)
plot(esignal * 10 + close/2, color=color.orange)

plot(lastLong, color=color.blue)
plot(lastShort, color=color.red)

plotshape(didRiseEnough, style=shape.arrowup, color=color.red)
plotshape(didFallEnough, style=shape.arrowdown, color=color.blue)

if (not inDateRange)
    strategy.close_all()
```

**Update 1:**
Below code is a work in progress, with some debugging.
You say: *the blue (lastLong) still updates more often than there are trades*.
That's because there could have been a trade there, because the conditions are valid for a trade at those update points. However, your strategy doesn't take a trade there, because in the properties of the strategy, `Pyramiding` is set to `1`. This means that your strategy will only take 1 order per direction at any time. If you increase `Pyramiding`, you'll see that trades will be taken at those update points. Now, it depends on what you want. Do you want to only take 1 trade per direction? Or do you only want to be in 1 position (long or short) at any time?

```
//@version=4

strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true)
// Variables
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
desiredGain = 1.05
desiredLoss = 1.025
var float lastLong = na
// lastLong := na(lastLong[1]) ? na : lastLong[1]
var float lastShort = na
// lastShort := na(lastShort[1]) ? na : lastShort[1]

inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021, 04, 01, 0, 0))// and (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021, 05, 16, 0, 0))

// Calculation
fastMA = ema(close, fastLength)
slowMA = ema(close, slowlength)
macd = fastMA - slowMA
signal = sma(macd, MACDLength)
esignal = ema(macd, MACDLength)
delta = macd - esignal

didRiseEnough = close/lastLong > desiredGain
didFallEnough = lastShort/close > desiredLoss

co = crossover(macd, esignal)
cu = crossunder(macd, esignal)

plotchar(na(lastLong),"na(lastLong)","")
plotchar(inDateRange and co, "inDateRange and co", "")
plotchar(inDateRange and co and didFallEnough, "inDateRange and co and didFallEnough", "")

if na(lastLong) // If lastLong is uninitialized, run the first entry without checking didFallEnough
    if (inDateRange and co)
        strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
        lastLong := close
else
    if (inDateRange and co and didFallEnough)
        strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
        lastLong := close
        
if na(lastShort) // If lastShort is uninitialized, run the first entry without checking didRiseEnough
    if (inDateRange and cu)
        strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
        lastShort := close
else
    if (inDateRange and cu and didRiseEnough)
        strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
        lastShort := close

// Plot
plot(macd * 10 + close/2, "macd", color=color.blue)
//plot(signal * 10 + close/2, color=color.orange)
plot(esignal * 10 + close/2, "esignal", color=color.orange)

plot(lastLong, "lastLong", color=color.blue)
plot(lastShort, "lastShort", color=color.red)

// plotshape(didRiseEnough, style=shape.arrowup, color=color.red)
// plotshape(didFallEnough, style=shape.arrowdown, color=color.blue)

if (not inDateRange)
    strategy.close_all()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. Unfortunately this made lastShort disappear completely from the view and lastLong still updates when trades don't happen. I will add another screenshot to the original question which hopefully shows all the required information.

Comment: Maybe i should start from scratch, all i want is MACD to send long & short but wait for a specific increase before selling, for example 5%.

Comment: added update 1 to my answer, with some questions for you.

Comment: Hi again, i don’t want pyramiding for now. How can it be changed to only update the variables on a strategy entry?

Comment: Tried the WIP but i understand it doesn't block pyramiding so I'm waiting for that update. Thank you so much for taking your time with this. I have worked with some other languages but this pine script is confusing and doesn't really offer much for debugging so it makes it quite challenging.

Comment: I've tried, but not quite there yet. Do you want to keep both a long AND short position open simultaneously? Or do you only want to have 1 position at any time? Also, if you enter a trade, I see that you have a price target, but do you also have a stop-loss for when the trade doesn't go your way? Can't see that in your code.

Comment: No, just one position at a time for now, still learning.